# Robo3t crashing in ubuntu 16.04 and above version (This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb")

Tags: linux, mongodb, robo3t, ubuntu-17.04

When i starting robo3t in ubuntu 16.04 version it is not opening, the error is show below like

**error:**

```
sony@sony:~/Documents/installed/robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/bin$ ./robo3t
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because if **libstdc++** folder library's simply make backup and start robot3t. Follow the given steps below and its working fine

**solution:**

```
mkdir ~/robo-backup
mv robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/lib/libstdc++* ~/robo-backup/
robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/bin/robo3t
```

Answer (score 0):

if you try to install latest version of **robomobo** that call be now **robo3t**. Or you try install on ubuntu 16.04 follow the below step and your robomongo install

Download latest robomongo tar file

```
wget https://download.robomongo.org/1.1.1/linux/robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0.tar.gz
```

Extract it

```
tar -xvzf https://download.robomongo.org/1.1.1/linux/robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0.tar.gz
```

Make a directory

```
mkdir ~/robo-backup
```

Move **robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/lib/libstdc++** direcotry  to **~/robo-backup/** direcotory

```
mv robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/lib/libstdc++* ~/robo-backup/
```

Run the robo3t

```
robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/bin/robo3t
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `lib/libstdc++*` will work.

[source](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1450#issuecomment-337152312)